# VmService timestamp does not correspond to the flutter driver timeline event timestamp

Tags: flutter, dart, virtual-machine, flutter-test, flutterdriver

I have dart test where I do

```
setUp() async {
  vm_service.VmService vms = await vmServiceConnectUri(vmUrl);
  vmsStartTime = (await vms.getVMTimelineMicros()).timestamp;
  await flutterDriver.startTracing()
}
tearDown() async {
  vmsEndTime = (await vms.getVMTimelineMicros()).timestamp;
  Timeline timeline = await driver.stopTracingAndDownloadTimeline();
}
```

Tests run for around 30 seconds each. And for some reason after the tests I have something like

```
vmsStartTime = 4323069605
vmsEndTime =   4323088753
```

In timeline first event timestampMicros is

```
"ts":                      4318344424
```

Also:

```
"timeOriginMicros": 4318344424,
"timeExtentMicros": 2080190
```

I use vmsStartTest and vmsEndTest to filter out events related to each tests and with such issues I miss all the events related to the test from the timeline. Please help me to understand why that happens and how to deal with it?

Answer (score 0):

For now using `traceAction` seems to give the best results. So each action I do during the test is a subject for `traceAction`. Timeline from each next `traceAction` is appended to global timeline json object (events are appended and duration is calculated as `customTimelineJson["timeExtentMicros"] = timeline.json["timeOriginMicros"] + timeline.json["timeExtentMicros"] - customTimelineJson["timeOriginMicros"];`
This helps to keep most of the events in the timeline. Test start time is mapped to the `timestampMicros` of the first event in the very first event in timeline. Test end is taken from the last event in the last timeline of the last `traceAction`. `timeOriginMicros` is taken from the first event of the very first `traceAction` timeline